# Inserting and Querying Date with MongoDB and Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date

I need some help finding a record by date in mongodb and nodejs.

I add the date to the json object in a scraping script as follows:

```
jsonObj.last_updated = new Date();
```

This object is inserted into mongodb. I can see it as follows:

```
 "last_updated" : "2014-01-22T14:56:59.301Z"
```

Then in my nodejs script I do a findOne():

```
 var jObj = JSON.parse(line.toString());

 collection.findOne(jObj,function(err, doc) {
   if (doc){
     console.log(doc._id);
   } else  {
     console.log('not found');
   }
 });
```

The object is not found. If I remove the last_updated field from the object it is found so it is definitely where the problem is.

If I isolate the field as follows:

```
collection.findOne({last_updated: '2014-01-22T14:56:59.301Z'},function(err, doc) {
  if (doc){
    console.log(doc._id);
  } else  {
    console.log('not found');
  }
});
```

Nothing comes back either. What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: `new Date(Date.now()).toISOString()`

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You need to pass a date object and not a date string.

```
collection.findOne({last_updated: new Date('2014-01-22T14:56:59.301Z')},function(err, doc) {
```

The MongoDB driver will transform it into `ISODate`:

```
{ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("52dfe0c469631792dba51770"), 
   "last_updated" : ISODate('2014-01-22T14:56:59.301Z') 
}
```

Check these questions:

- [MongoDB + nodejs : how to query ISODate fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561381/mongodb-nodejs-how-to-query-isodate-fields)
- [ISODate is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848314/isodate-is-not-defined)

Comment: Combining with momentjs `Items.find({sellingState: "Active", endTime: {$lt: new Date(moment().subtract(1, 'day').toISOString())}}, {limit: 10})`

Comment: To store now use `new Date` without the parens

Comment: Yup. Do **not** use ```new Date().toISOString()``` when inserting into MongoDB database (instead just use ```new Date()```) because MongDB already does the conversion for you and .toISOString() will make .find() operators or $gte operators on the database fail

Comment: Using `new Date` without the parentheses (using Node 12.18 and mongo 3.4.1) gives me the same result in the document (a UTC ISODate) as using it with the parentheses, i.e. `new Date()`

Answer (score 14):

To clarify. What is important to know is that:

- Yes, you have to pass a Javascript Date object.
- Yes, it has to be ISODate friendly
- Yes, from my experience getting this to work, you need to manipulate the date to ISO
- Yes, working with dates is generally always a tedious process, and mongo is no exception

Here is a working snippet of code, where we do a little bit of date manipulation to ensure Mongo can handle it correctly. In this example, I am using mongoose module and want results for rows whose date attribute is less than (ie. before) the date given as myDate param.

```
var inputDate = new Date(myDate.toISOString());
MyModel.find({
    'date': { $lte: inputDate }
})
```

Comment: how does the myDate param look like ? Is it the string 'Mon Feb 29 2016 21:04:59 GMT+0100 (CET)' ?

Comment: I believe this is incorrect and made the same mistake which caused errors in my existing database. Do **not** use ```new Date().toISOString()``` when inserting into MongoDB database (instead just use ```new Date()```) because MongDB already does the conversion for you and .toISOString() will make .find() operators or $gte operators on the database fail

Answer (score 7):

I recently ran into the same issue and I wanted to add some additional info.

You can insert dates in two ways:

1. Created on the nodejs server side (e.g. in a ExpressJS script)

example: insert a new object and time stamp it

```
db.collection('mycollection').findOneAndUpdate({'name': req.body.name}, {
  // only "update" if it's an insert, meaning name is not found
  $setOnInsert: {
    'name': req.body.name,
    'date_added': new Date()
  }
}, { 
  upsert: true
}, (err, result) => {
  if(err) return res.send(err);
  res.send(result);
});
```

2. Created on the client side from JS and then sent over the wire using a REST API in a JSON object via a POST request

example:

```
// Send POST Request here
fetch('addDate', {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  body: JSON.stringify({
    'date_added':  new Date()
  })
})
```

For 1. and 2. you create the dates using the 
`new Date('2014-01-22T14:56:59.301Z')` function as explained in the answers above. The difference is that if you do it as in 1. on the server side using the MongoClient package it is stored as a `ISODate('2014-01-22T14:56:59.301Z')` in MongoDB. 
If you do it as in 2. on the client side it is stored as a String: `'2014-01-22T14:56:59.301Z'` in MongoDB.

To query the ISODate object you need to use `new Date('2014-01-22T14:56:59.301Z')` or `ISODate('2014-01-22T14:56:59.301Z')`
To query the string you use just the string: `'2014-01-22T14:56:59.301Z'`

Here are some query samples using the mongo shell:

Date stored as String:

```
db.mycollection.findOne({date_added {$gte:'2018-06-22T00:07:53.688Z'}})
```

This returns

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b2c3dd90078ce3cd484ef21"),
  "name" : "alfons",
  "date_added" : "2018-06-22T00:07:53.688Z"
}
```

Date stored as ISODate:

```
db.mycollection.findOne({date_added: {$lte: ISODate('2018-06-26T23:24:37.023Z')}})
```

or using "new Date" instead:

```
db.mycollection.findOne({date_added: {$lte: new Date('2018-06-26T23:24:37.023Z')}
```

This returns:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b2bb21e1954b104e61ff735"),
  "name" : "ceasar",
  "date_added" : ISODate("2018-06-21T14:11:41.323Z")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add Default key in Schema and value to Date.now()

Comment: How do you add a default key in the Schema?

Comment: `publishedAt:{
            type:Date,
            default:Date.now()
        }`

Answer (score -1):

If your using timestamps data to query. EG : "createdAt" : "2021-07-12T16:06:34.949Z"

```
const start  = req.params.id; //2021-07-12
const data = await Model.find({
            "createdAt": {
              '$gte': `${start}T00:00:00.000Z`,
              '$lt': `${start}T23:59:59.999Z`
            }
          });
console.log(data);
```

it will show the data of particular date .i.,e in this case. "2021-07-12"

Comment: Hard coding time in an ISO string is simply not an answer to OPs question.