# How to create UTC Time in Express for Mongo Query in Express.js

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

This has probably been asked a hundred times, yet I dare to ask: In express / mongoose I need to create a UTC ISO date in order to query MongoDB. This is what I am doing:

```
var date = new Date(req.params.date + " 00:00:00 UTC").toUTCString();
```

Whereas req.params.date equals this string: `2015-01-01`.

Above line creates: `Mon, 12 Jan 2015 00:00:00 GMT`, in MongoDB I have:

```
"date" : ISODate("2014-12-08T00:00:00.000Z")
```

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to represent the date in your query as a standard JavaScript `Date` object.

So leave off the `toUTCString()` part and something like this will work:

```
var date = new Date(req.params.date);
collection.findOne({date: date}, callback);
```

The `ISODate` stuff confuses so many people (myself included for the longest time).  `ISODate` is just a MongoDB shell construct, date objects are stored as 64-bit integer [BSON Date](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#date) objects in MongoDB.

Comment: Funny, yours also works, obviously the MongoDB Driver is capable of handling both formats.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `toUTCString()` I used the `toISOString()` method of the `Date` object, this worked fine.

```
var date = new Date(req.params.date + " 00:00:00 UTC").toISOString();
```

Also see. [Inserting and Querying Date with MongoDB and Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286599/inserting-and-querying-date-with-mongodb-and-nodejs/21286896#21286896)

Answer (score 0):

Convert UTC string to Date Object

```
    var utc_date=new Date(new Date().toUTCString());
```