# Unable to query mongodb dateTime field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I know this question has been asked earlier been none of the solutions worked for me.

I want to query a collection with `createdAt` of type `DateTime`. It seems to work perfectly in mongo shell but it returns empty array in `Node.js`. I am using following code:

```
{ 
 '$gte':new Date().toISOString()
}
```

Comment: The syntax looks OK.  Have you got more context to the query?

Comment: new Date().toISOString() returns "2017-06-26T16:05:06.365Z" which doesn't properly queries the `createdAt` and returns null

Comment: Are you using mongo native driver in your node application for query ?

Comment: yes [mongodb](https://npmjs.com/package/mongodb)

Comment: @AnubhavSingh any solutions regarding this?

Comment: I believe if your createdAt field had the DateTime type then your query shouldn't have worked in mongo shell. 
Can you show the example of createdAt property in a document? How does it look?

Comment: `createdAt` is of DateTime, here it is: [document schema](https://api.cloudboost.io/file/bgzujymlzaxm/JrQaeuET.PNG) [QueryResult](https://api.cloudboost.io/file/bgzujymlzaxm/HiwTjVKb.PNG)

Comment: In your example in the mongo shell you are giving the date 21-06-2017 as the argument for greater than but in your question you have new Date().  new Date() will give you the date at the time you run the script.  Could that be why you are not getting the expected result?

Comment: No that's just an example I have used

Answer (score 1):

You are querying a string instead of a date object.  I would suggest using

```
new Date()
```

Instead of

```
new Date().toISOString()
```

and see if that works for you.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/

Comment: ISODate is not defined in `nodejs` . I have tried `new Date()` as well, it doesn't works too.

Comment: Here is a much better explanation and possible solution for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286599/inserting-and-querying-date-with-mongodb-and-nodejs/21286896#21286896

Answer (score 0):

You can use `momentjs` as :

```
moment.format()
```

or

```
moment.utc().format()
```

to create the timestamp.
 `MomentJS` will come really handy for other purposes as well.

Comment: it returns same string as `new Date().toISOString()` `"2017-06-26T16:05:06.365Z"`