# How to Format a new Date() in JavaScript into an ISODate in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

In mongodb I have some dates stored in a ISODate such as:

```
ISODate("2017-02-06T18:04:34.954+0000")
```

By using foo = new Date(); However, in one certain cases it shows up as a string:

```
"2017-10-05T20:33:59.453Z"
```

Is there a way of consistency getting the ISODate("2017-02-06T18:04:34.954+0000") result shown above using JavaScript?

Comment: use momentjs https://momentjs.com/

Comment: I'm unable to install anything to this project due to restrictions... Is there another basic work around?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/date-and-time-strings-javascript

Comment: Have you checked MDN Docs on [.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)?

Comment: I have tried .toISOString() :( no luck.

Comment: To clarify I was looking for the first result, not second. My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
let myDate = new Date();
let myISODate = myDate.toISOString();
console.log(myISODate)
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: To clarify I was looking for the first result, not second. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

```
var javaScriptDateObject= new Date();
var newIsoString = foo.toISOString();
```

Referencing this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286599/inserting-and-querying-date-with-mongodb-and-nodejs/21286896#21286896) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25040541/1684254); 
The MongoDB driver will transform it into `ISODate`:

```
{ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("52dfe0c469631792dba51770"), 
   "last_updated" : ISODate('2014-01-22T14:56:59.301Z') 
}
```

Comment: .toISOString() is not working, it's coming up as a string not in the ISODate(...) format. Sorry!

Comment: To clarify I was looking for the first result, not second. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was unrelated to the format, ended up being a quick reboot to node to fix the issue. Thanks.