# Convert Date to MongoDB ISO Date

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb

I have a date that is in this format in my MongoDB database.

```
{
      "_id": ObjectId("5682e899f326d45c821d8b9b"),
      "City": "Atlanta",
      "Date": "12/5/02",
      "Temp": 78.5,
}
```

I would like to convert this to ISO date so I could sort on date in my database. What would be the best way to do this with an update command with PyMongo or JavaScript.

Comment: Do you want to update your documents by changing `Date` to ISODate?

Comment: you need to read documents, add date object and then save them again

Answer (score 1):

Mongo has moved on quite a bit since I last used it but as far as I know, as has been suggested elsewhere you are going to have to load and update each record in turn.

You have two problems. The first is that your date format is ambiguous. The example date you give will have different values depending on the locale of the system used to parse it as a date. In the US it is (I think) December the 5th 2002. On my side of the atlantic though it will parse as 12th May 2002. Funtimes.

Assuming you **know** the intented format of each date then in node you could use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) to parse each date to a fixed format for example

```
let date = moment(document.Date, "D/M/YY");
```

and then output as an ISO date using

```
document.Date = date.toISOString();
```

or if you are being good, and doing it non-destructively

```
document.ISODate = date.toISOString();
```

although now you have two dates to look after...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate over the entire result set, and update each document individually like so:

```
var f = function(e) {
    var arr = e['Date'].split("/");

    //assuming "Date" field was formatted as "YY/MM/DD"
    var date_obj = new Date(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);

    db.your_collection.update({_id: e['_id']}, {$set: {date_obj: date_obj}});    
}


db.your_collection.find().forEach(f)
```

If you want to remove your old field, you can run the following:

```
db.your_collection.update({}, {$unset: {Date: 1}}, {multi:true});
```

But don't do that until you are sure your dates were converted correctly.

Comment: Using bulk operations would make this more efficient.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg - how would Bulk operations work if the update `date_obj` value is different for each document?

Comment: Of the top of my head for 2.6: `var bulk = db.c.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(); var f = function(e){... var d = ...; bulk.find(query).update(upDoc);}; db.c.find(query).forEach(f); bulk.execute()`. Accordingly for 3.0

Answer (score -1):

I think, you should first retrieve the records and use a loop to change all. Then you should parse the data to construct a `Date` object to convert to mongo date.

```
var value = "12/5/02";
var parts = value.split("/");
var dt = new Date("20"+parts[2], parseInt(parts[1])-1, parts[0]);
```

If you are using nodejs, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257911/create-an-iso-date-object-in-javascript) too.

Edit: I assumed 12=day, 5=month.

Comment: Did you run your code against the example date provided? I don't think it does what you were hoping it would

Comment: @Andy why not do you think ?

Comment: Because when I run it it comes out with an incorrect date.

Comment: Are you checking it in pure javascript or in mongodb ?

Comment: It works in web page. I ll also check in mongodb console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99259/discussion-between-andy-and-ardabeyazoglu).

Comment: I edited the answer to be correct. The last argument must be parts[0].