# Is there a way to convert javascript Date object to string but retain the format as displayed when console.log is used on the Date object?

Tags: javascript

I want to convert the date object to string but I want it in the same format as it is displayed when I do `console.log(new Date())` which is something like '2019-05-21T11:55:39.496Z' and not the usual extended format we get when we do `console.log(new Date().toString())` which is something like this 'Tue May 21 2019 17:28:51 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)'.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257911/create-an-iso-date-object-in-javascript

Answer (score -1):

```
console.log(new Date().toISOString())
2019-05-21T12:03:50.601Z
```