# Mongoose Scheme Type For Time

Tags: java, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I am creating a MERN stack application, a booking site, where the user can choose a particular time for the event. What data type do I use to store time?

Answer (score 1):

You can require the date on node.js with this code:

```
var isodate = new Date().toISOString(); // date in iso format
```

and when you want to store with mongoose you choose the **Date** data type.

Code link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257911/create-an-iso-date-object-in-javascript]

Data types: [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_datatype.htm]